# phonegap asset catatlog - need a tutorial

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to set the splash and icons in ios.

The app is build with cordova cli 3.3

What ever I do I cannot get slash to show my image on ipad - I get either white screen or the default cordova image.

I've upgraded this app from manual build of phonegap 2.9 where the splash seems to be working fine.

On iphone the splash is displayed.

every time I create a app i waste a few hours playing with it until it show how works.

I wish someone could explain to me how they ment for the asset catalog to work, and what is the fastest way to get the icon/splash into the app.

how come there is no tool to simply throw the images in?

Answer (score 0):

The default Cordova splash images are located at www/res/screens. Within that folder there are platform specific folders that allow you to define splash images for each platform.

The name of the image is based in different conventions for each platform and are documented at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens.

I believe Cordova 3 introduced a config.xml file in www. You should enable the splash screen plugin for your device in that file as per the above documentation. The Cordova CLI should copy the appropriate resources to your platform folder when you do a build.

You should also install the Splash Screen plugin using the CLI by following the instructions at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

Comment: mmm... I dont have www/res/screens folder.